# Scraping elements without an id or class from a web page using Python BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I know how to scrape data from a web page if the element has an id or class.

e.g. Here, `soup` is a BeautifulSoup object.

```
for item in soup.findAll('a',{"class":"class_name"}):
    title = item.string
    print(title+"\n")
```

How can we do this if the element has no id or class? For example, a paragraph element without an id or class.

Or in an even worse case, what happens if we need to just scrape some plain text like the following?

```
<body>
<p>YO!</p>
hello world!!
</body>
```

How can I print only `hello world!!` in the above page source, for example?
It has no id or class.

Comment: I removed your second question because it's off-topic for [so]. However, do you mean `soup.find('body')` or `soup.find_all('body')`?

Comment: I don't know what those two above statements are for. If you tell me, i can answer your question. :)

Comment: Ah, fine. However, about *what are some other good scraping packages other than BeautifulSoup?* is a **primarily opinion-based** question. Which is off-topic for this site. Please **don't ask them**. If you take a look at your question you can see my edit, I removed them. [Here's what's on-topic questions on this site.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: And my questions are your question's answers. I meant *Are you looking for `soup.find('body')` or `soup.find_all('body')`?*

Comment: OK. So executed the above two commands. They basically print the full page source between the body tags, one including the tags and the other not including them. I want to print a part of this. Not all of it. I edited the question for your clarity.

Comment: Ah...that...you can extract (delete) all of the tags inside that tag (in this case, it's `body` tag). Check my answer for it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to locate an element specifically having no defined `id` and `class` attributes:

```
soup.find("p", class_=False, id=False)
```

To locate the "text" nodes like `hello world!!` in your example, you can either get it by the text itself - via a partial match, or a regular expression match:

```
import re

soup.find(text=re.compile("^hello"))  # find text starting with "hello"
soup.find(text="hello world!!")  # find text with an exact "hello world!!" text
soup.find(text=lambda text: text and "!!" in text)  # find text havin "!!" inside it
```

Or, you can locate that preceding `p` element and get the [next text node](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-next-siblings-and-find-next-sibling):

```
soup.find("p", class_=False, id=False).find_next_sibling(text=True)
soup.find("p", text="YO!").find_next_sibling(text=True)
```

Answer (score 2):

However, if you just want to get the text inside the `body` tag, but don't want the text in it's any tags.

You could use [`tag.find_all()`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-all) to get all of the tags in it, and then use [`tag.extract()`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#extract) remove them. Then you'll get a `body` tag with only the text in it.

For example:

```
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup('''\
... <body>
... <p>YO!</p>
... hello world!!
... </body>
... ''')

>>> print(soup.get_text())

YO!
hello world!!


>>> print(soup.find('body').get_text())

YO!
hello world!!

>>> for tag in soup.find('body').find_all():
...     tag.extract()
...     
... 
<p>YO!</p>
>>> print(soup.find('body').get_text())


hello world!!

>>> print(soup.find('body').get_text(strip=True))
hello world!!
>>>
```